# Android: Enable certain button with id as index

Tags: android, android-button, android-resources

I have 50 styled buttons with identificators like "level_i", I need to enable button with certain i in id.
I have code to work with indexed aarays in string xml, but I have no proper ideas how to change it for my usage

```
Class<R.id.array> res;
Field field;
try {
res = R.array.class;
field = res.getField("words_" + fname);
//set myString to the string resource myArray[fname,y]
myString = getResources().obtainTypedArray(field.getInt(null)).getString(y);
}
catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are saying that you have an ID resource named `"words_" + fname` for example `R.id.words_100`. If that is correct, then you can first get the ID using the name of the resource with getIdentifier. Then you can get the actual ID, then you can find the view with that ID:

```
String resName = "words_" + fname";
Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(resName, "id", getPackageName());
View button = findViewById(resId);
```

EDIT:

Modified original answer to fetch resources from R.id rather than R.string-array.

Comment: I've modified my answer to have it just be the button ID.